# How is the [:] method being used here? I think it's not necessary

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

I want to know why the developer used sentence[:] instead of sentence. It seems to make no difference.

For the input, snippet and phrase would be something like:

```
snippet = "Have a %%%%"
phrase = "What a %%%"
```

Here is the code I'm looking at.

```
 for sentence in snippet, phrase:
            result = sentence[:]
            for word in class_names:
                result = result.replace("%%%", word, 1)
```

The abridged version is that there are two variables, snippet and phrase, that are strings, that may have %%% in them, and will be replaced by a word that is defined earlier on in the program as the variable "word."

Does anyone know why this person would use [:]

Side question, does

```
for i in j, k
```

just iterate from j to k?

---

Full context for the context junkies out there. It's from Learn Python the Hard way. My comments are also included.

```
import random
from urllib import urlopen
import sys

#URL used to populate words
WORD_URL = "http://learncodethehardway.org/words.txt"
#A list of words
WORDS = []

#A dict of phrases structured "Code" : "English explanation of code"
#Each phrase has %%% @@@ or *** which are not explained in this section
#Because these placeholders are not unique and are not variables, the english and code must match
#In a way where the variables for both are in the exact same order.
PHRASES = {
    "class %%%(%%%):":
      "Make a class named %%% that is-a %%%.",
    "class %%%(object):\n\tdef __init__(self, ***)" :
      "class %%% has-a __init__ that takes self and *** parameters.",
    "class %%%(object):\n\tdef ***(self, @@@)":
      "class %%% has-a function named *** that takes self and @@@ parameters.",
    "*** = %%%()":
      "Set *** to an instance of class %%%.",
    "***.***(@@@)":
      "From *** get the *** function, and call it with parameters self, @@@.",
    "***.*** = '***'":
      "From *** get the *** attribute and set it to '***'."
}

# do they want to drill phrases first
#if the user inputs "english" into the command line as an argument (and nothing else) set Phrase First to True, otherwise its false
#This should allow the user to choose whether the drill in code first or english by typing or not typing English into the command line
if len(sys.argv) == 2 and sys.argv[1] == "english":
    PHRASE_FIRST = True
else:
    PHRASE_FIRST = False

# load up the words from the website
#urlopen returns a file that should represent what is on the website Word_Url
#specifically, the website linked in this program is a text file that just has one word per line
#the file like object created by urlopen supports standard file i/o commands from python
#readlines reads every line within the file like object that represents the website

#this uses a for loop to iterate through each of the words from the website provided and append them to the WORDS list
#while using the strip() method to remove all whitespace, in this case, the /n that separates each word
#You will end up with a clean list of words named WORDS
for word in urlopen(WORD_URL).readlines():
    WORDS.append(word.strip())

#defines function convert that takes input snippet, phrase and has class_names, other_names, results, params, and two loops
def convert(snippet, phrase):
    #runs the capitalize function on a random word from WORDS,
    #specifically the sample method from random is called with WORDS and snippet.count("%%%") args
    #this will use the list of WORDS as the population to pull a random word from
    #it will also count the number of %%%'s in the snippet 
    #and use that as the argument for the amount of words random.sample() will retrieve
    #The for loop should then loop through each word that was retrieved and capitalize it
    #these capitalized words are then stored in class_names for later use
    #This is a local variable so it will reset every time convert is called
    class_names = [w.capitalize() for w in random.sample(WORDS, snippet.count("%%%"))]
    #this does the same as above except it does not capitalize and it searches for the number of ***'s instead
    other_names = random.sample(WORDS, snippet.count("***"))
    #sets two empty lists
    results = []
    param_names = []

    #loops for an amount of times equal to the number of @@@ symbols in the snippet
    for i in range(0, snippet.count("@@@")):
        #sets new var param_count = to a number beween 1-3
        param_count = random.randint(1,3)
        #It retrieves words from WORDS the same way that class_names and other_names do, however
        #It uses param_count's random int value instead of counting anything from a snippet
        #it then joins each word with ', ' and appends it to the empty param_names list
        param_names.append(', '.join(random.sample(WORDS, param_count)))

    #by now we should have random words prepared for any %%%, ***, and @@@ symbols in the list
    #and we should have between 1 and 3 random words stored in list param_names


    #now we create a loop that should iterate through a dictionary key pair of snippet and phrase
    #sentence will first return snippet, then phrase?
    for sentence in snippet, phrase:
        #I honestly don't understand this at all
        #it will change more when I understand what is being input
        print sentence
        result = sentence[:]
        print result
        #This loop iterates through class_names and replaces %%% in result with the current word from classnames
        #.replace method targets %%% and replaces it with the current word in class_names, and it limits this replacement to one at a time
        #it will set result == to a new version of itself, where the next %%% will get replaced the current word in class_names
        for word in class_names:
            result = result.replace("%%%", word, 1)

        #same as above with ***
        for word in other_names:
            result = result.replace("***", word, 1)

        #same as above with @@@
        for word in param_names:
            result = result.replace("@@@", word, 1)

        #appends the empty results list as defined in the beginning of the function with result
        #then it returns reults
        results.append(result)

    return results

# keep going until they hit CTRL-D
#try Except loopt that only stops at EOFerror which is ctrl D? Otherwise...
try:
    while True:
        #new variable snippets is equal to a list of all of the keys (code) in PHRASES
        snippets = PHRASES.keys()
        #it shuffles the snippets
        random.shuffle(snippets)

        #it iterates through the snippets one at a time
        for snippet in snippets:
            #new var phrase uses the snippet as the key to set itself (phrase) to that keys value
            #at this point, snippet == one Code phrase and phrase equals the resulting English phrase
            phrase = PHRASES[snippet]
            #new vars question, answer equal to snippet and phrase being run through convert
            question, answer = convert(snippet, phrase)
            if PHRASE_FIRST:
                question, answer = answer, question

            print question

            raw_input("> ")
            print "ANSWER:  %s\n\n" % answer
except EOFError:
    print "\nBye"
ooptest.py
Open with
Displaying ooptest.py.
```

Comment: `sentence[:]` makes a *copy*, and for your loop question `for i in j, k`, the  writing of `j, k` will make a tuple. So you are iterating over the tuple of `j, k`.

Comment: It makes a copy. Then the copy can be changed without disturbing the original.

Comment: @wwii Yeah... But making a copy of a string is pointless because strings are immutable.

Comment: It makes a copy indeed, but since it's a string it's meaningless because strings are immutable... you can get rid of that piece of code, use `sentence` directly instead of copying it and you should get the exact same functionality.

Comment: `` for i in j, k``` - did you try it?

Comment: If you don't make a copy, result will point to sentence and you will  change sentence. If you had tried it before asking you would have seen that. The point of doing those exercises is to do them

Comment: @wwii you're talking very arrogantly which I would accept if you were correct, but you aren't :)

Comment: Interesting. I want to know why anyone would use the [:] operator at all. IIRC it iterates from the beginning to the end of something. It was explained as being used with functions like del, so that you can delete the interior of a list, without deleting the list itself, leaving it to take more variable assignations. It seems like there's really no reason for the [:] in this code, it's just extra computational power? – user2208569 4 mins ago    edit

Comment: @user2208569 Removed my answer, but to answer your question: this summarises what's wrong with LPTHW and recommends some other resources instead: https://sopython.com/wiki/LPTHW_Complaints

Comment: @alfasin I stand chastised, I hate it when I do that.

Comment: @viraptor, just to set the record straight, I didn't remove any of your answers. I upvoted them all. I am not sure how they would have been removed.

Answer (score 0):

If we clean all the "surrounding noise" we're left with something like the following:

```
snippet = "Have a %%%%"
phrase = "What a %%%"
for sentence in snippet, phrase:
    result = sentence[:]
```

Since both `snippet` and `phrase` are strings they are immutable, so all the computation below can be done directly on `sentence` without the need to "make a copy".

You didn't understand this code simply because it's doing something meaningless...

Comment: People are also saying that "result = sentence[:]" makes a copy of sentence. 

But, I'm not interested in duplication of strings via assigning it to a new variable. 

Instead, I want to know why anyone would use the [:] operator at all. IIRC it iterates from the beginning to the end of something.

It was explained as being used with functions like del, so that you can delete the interior of a list, without deleting the list itself, leaving it to take more variable assignations.

It seems like there's really no reason for the [:] in this code, it's just extra computational power?

Comment: @user2208569 exactly. The `[:]` operator makes sense when running on lists (because they are mutable) but it's totally useless when applied to strings.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I wanted to know :D

It was also great learning that the `for i in j,k` creates tuple `(j, k)` to iterate